# Remove letters matching pattern before and after the required string

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector with the following elements:

```
myvec<- c("output.chr10.recalibrated", "output.chr11.recalibrated",
"output.chrY.recalibrated")
```

I want to selectively extract the value after `chr` and before `.recalibrated` and get the `result`.

Result:

```
10, 11, Y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to do this.  We match one of more characters (`.*`) that follow 'chr' (`(?<=chr)`) and before the `.recalibrated` (`(?=\\.recalibrated)`).

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(myvec, "(?<=chr).*(?=\\.recalibrated)")
 #[1] "10" "11" "Y"
```

Or use `gsub` to match the characters until `chr` or (`|`) that starts from `.recalibrated` to the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with `''`.

```
 gsub(".*\\.chr|\\.recalibrated.*$", "", myvec)
 #[1] "10" "11" "Y"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the difference between `?<=chr` and `?=\\`?

Comment: @MAPK We are using regex lookarounds to select one or more elements between those `chr` and reclibrated

Comment: @MAPK: Lookarounds (zero-width assertions that only check if some text can be matched or not matched before or after the current location in string) are necessary with `str_extract` because this function does not keep captured values.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with a mere `sub`:

```
> sub(".*?chr(.*?)\\.recalibrated.*", "\\1", myvec)
[1] "10" "11" "Y"
```

The pattern  matches any symbols before the first `chr`, then matches and captures any characters up to the first `.recalibrated`, and then matches the rest of the characters. In the replacement pattern, we use a backreference `\1` that inserts the captured value you need back into the resulting string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN2zS5/1)

As an alternative, use `str_match`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_match(myvec, "chr(.*?)\\.recalibrated")[,2]
[1] "10" "11" "Y"
```

It keeps all captured values and helps avoid costly unanchored lookarounds in the pattern that are necessary in `str_extract`.

The pattern means:

- `chr` - match a sequence of literal characters `chr`
- `(.*?)` - match any characters other than a newline (if you need to match newlines, too, add `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern) up to the first
- `\\.recalibrated` - `.recalibrated` literal character sequence.

Comment: Just for my own mind sanity: `[.]chr([^.]*)[.]` should be far enough as regex  in this specific case. (not dot character just after chr included between two dots).

Comment: Side note: upvoted for the completeness of answer clearly explaining how it works, may worth a note about `*?` for non greedy match to be even better IMO)

Comment: Sorry, was very busy. `*?` is a [**lazy quantifier**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), right, I just wanted to explain the pattern in human words (*... up to the **first** `.recalibrated`*). I would not use `([^.]*)` because it won't match if there is a dot between `chr` and `.recalibrated`. **If** that cannot occur, then yes, I would.

Comment: Fair enough ;) Now OP's has the two side of how his/her Q can be interpreted and that's already far too much attention IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers failing in case of slightly different inputs like `whatever.chr10.whateverelse.recalibrated` here's my own approach only differing on the regex part with `sub`:

```
sub(".*[.]chr([^.]*)[.].*", "\\1", myvec)
```

what the regex does is:

- `.*[.]chr` match as much as possible until finding '.chr' literraly
- `([^.]*)` capture everything not a dot after chr (could be replaced by `\\d+` to capture only numeric values, requiring at least one digit present
- `[.].*` match the rest of the line after a literal dot

I prefer the character class escape of dots (`[.]`) on the backslash escape (`\\.`) as it's usually easier to read when you're back on the regex, that's my my opinion and not covered by any best practice I know of.

Comment: But why do you have `whatever.chef10` when we want to remove `chr`?

Comment: @MAPK it was a typo ;) fixed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XY problem. Why extract? If this is needed in further analysis steps, we could for example do this instead:

```
for(chrN in c(1:22, "X", "Y")) {
  myVar <- paste0("output.chr", chrN, ".recalibrated")
  #do some fun stuff with myVar 
  print(myVar)
}
```